# Passing object with reactive properties as a prop triggers child component onUpdated hook when updating parent component state

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-composition-api, vue-props

Consider a simple component `Comp.vue` file that only logs a message in the console when updated:

```js
// Comp.vue

<script setup>
  import { onUpdated } from 'vue'
  onUpdated(() => {
    console.log('updated component')
  })
</script>
<template></template>
```

An `App.vue` file mounts `Comp.vue` and also logs a message in its `onUpdated` hook:

```js
// App.vue

<script setup>
  import Comp from './Comp.vue'
  import { ref, onUpdated } from 'vue'

  onUpdated(() => {
    console.log('updated parent')
  })

  const text = ref('')
  const data = ref()
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="text"/>
  <Comp/>
</template>
```

There's a `text` ref binded to an input element to trigger `onUpdated` on the parent. At this point, writing on the text input only logs `'updated parent'` in the console.

If an object with a reactive property is passed to `Comp` as a prop, writing on the input text logs both `'updated component'` and `'updated parent'` in the console:

```js
<Comp :data={ data }/>
```

That is, `Comp`'s `onUpdated` hook is being triggered with changes to `App`'s state. Here's a [demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9kstOwzAQRX9l5E1aqaQLWJW0EqAuYAGIx86bKJmGlMS2bKdUivLvzOTVIqUsqspzr50zM7cWd8aEhwrFSkQusbnx4NBXZiNVXhptPTzo0sDO6hKCcMkHtgejXIPF3QK0+jRp7DGFpjd3LqkSrZwHj0cPa/bOgmA+VOlG3FepJtX4ymw2h/UGaqkA2KoLDAudzYKq/4qJLSrPLzX0i5YdO1HTwWNpCnLRCSDKlak8HK5KnWKxloJJpFh2YtvcijFIqfm/6bRoefaKWAjvCGOXZ+HeaUXDasmkSOh+XqB9MT4nTClWHTNrcVHon6e25m2Fi6GefGHyPVHfuyPXpHi16NAeUIpR87HNkLBZ3r4/ty2MInVWFeT+R3xDGmHFjJ3tvlIpYZ/5WtrHdqe5yj7c9uhRuaEpBmVn0/qloOXy6C61fsK9Dm/ae7QnmuIQn4m0AYyBms7SLXsmA3IhIrwbrfqUEMLfnJxScrZq0fwCGMAHEQ==).

To avoid this, a computed property could be passed instead:

```js
const computedData = computed(() => ({ data: data.value }))
// ...
<Comp :data="computedData"/>
```

However, I'd like to know why passing `{ data }` directly causes `Comp` `onUpdated` hook to be triggered when `text` is updated.

Comment: Because you specified an object in a template and it's created on each render, `{ data } !== { data }`